# Adding Apollo client mutation in react bootstrap datatable

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I am able to get the Apollo query component in my application. But I'm having a hard time adding the mutation. I have the mutation query written out. I want to use the row and cellvalue from the `cellEditProp` hook function and pass them into the mutation component. I am having a hard time figuring out where to nest or wrap the mutation component. Any tips are much appreciated.

```
function onSaveCell(row, cellName, cellValue) {

    //Need to use this data for the mutation
}

function onBeforeSaveCell(row, cellName, cellValue) {
    console.log(cellName, cellValue, row

    );
    return true;
}

const cellEditProp = {
    mode: 'click',
    blurToSave: true,
    beforeSaveCell: onBeforeSaveCell, // a hook for before saving cell
    afterSaveCell: onSaveCell  // a hook for after saving cell
};


const APPROVALCHAIN_QUERY = gql`
    {
      vApprovalChainApproverCountList{
        applicationId
        applicationName
        collectionName
        licenseType
        cost
        approvers

      }
    }
    `;
const ADDCOST_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation updateCostlicense($costLicense: ApplicaitonCostInput!){
  updateCostLicense(costLicense: $costLicense){
    applicationId
    cost
    licenseType
  }
}
`;



class ApprovalRecord2 extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Query
                query={APPROVALCHAIN_QUERY}
            >
                {({ loading, error, data }) => {
                    if (loading)
                        return <p>Loading...</p>;

                    if (error)
                        return <p>{error.message}</p>;

                    const chain = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.vApprovalChainApproverCountList));
                    console.log(chain);

                    return (
                        <div>
                            <h1>ApprovalRecord2</h1>
                            <p>Add/Remove Approvers</p>

                                    <BootstrapTable data={chain} striped hover pagination search options={options} cellEdit={cellEditProp} version='4'>
                                        <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='applicationId' dataSort={true}>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
                                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='applicationName' dataSort={true}>Application</TableHeaderColumn>
                                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='collectionName' dataSort={true}>Collection</TableHeaderColumn>
                                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='licenseType' dataSort={true}>License</TableHeaderColumn>
                                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='cost' dataSort={true}>Cost</TableHeaderColumn>
                                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='approvers' dataSort={true}>Approvers</TableHeaderColumn>

                                    </BootstrapTable>

                                )}
                        </div>
                    );
                }}
            </Query>
        );
    }
}
export default ApprovalRecord2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass/inject (multiple, named) mutations (and queries) as props to component with [graphql()](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/docs/source/basics/mutations.md#calling-mutations)

Comment: How do I wrap the mutation component around my return? any examples?

Comment: Using components have drawbacks - `<Mutation/>` component in `render` can't inject props into entire component scope. You can try using currying but it's not worth the effort. With `compose()` you can use any number of them anywhere you need w/o building `rendering hell`.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to an example where I can read up on compose()? Thanks for responding.

Comment: [apollo-universal-starter-kit](https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-universal-starter-kit/blob/master/packages/client/src/modules/post/containers/PostComments.jsx)

Comment: I feel more lost now. Still cannot wrap my head around how to use it in the above example.

Comment: You can use [this example](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/docs/source/basics/mutations.md#custom-arguments) at start (mutation `submitRepository` passed as `submit` prop) to use in existing code - but mixing styles isn't good idea. Later you have to refactor it removing query component, using compose to inject queried data and mutation into entire component - in both cases it's standard HOC technique similiar to passing data and handlers as props (standard react parent-child passing). Find some tutorials if ou're still confused.